# How to install 3rd party library of dart

Tags: dart, libraries, dart-pub

When I browse [mongo-dart](https://bitbucket.org/vadimtsushko/mongo-dart), I found it using a 3rd-party libary [log4dart](https://github.com/Qalqo/log4dart).

I don't find any document of how to install it. Is there a library manager for dart? Do I have to copy the sources of log4dart into my project to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart curretly does not ship with a package manager (although one is expected to arrive any day now). So to install **log4dart** you will have to grab it directly from [github](https://github.com/qalqo/log4dart).

Comment: Look for pub, the package manager for Dart, coming soon. Bob Nystrom posted a quick update to the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/misc/I$20just$20gave$20a$20demo$20on$20pub/misc/v7jQZK4BoS0/355yzoO4_pkJ